# Repeating Max(timestamp) value for all the duplicate ID rows in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

This might be simple, but I am having troubles resolving this issue
I have a table with following columns and data :
[image]

There are multiple entries for an id with different updateTimestamp, I want to identify the max timestamp and repeat that value for all the duplicate ids in the table. Also, the table is large and I do not want to query it multiple times(process is complex).

Here is what I am expecting the output to look like
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find maximum of update timestamp for each ID and update the table using ID column. Something like

```
    update <table_name> tgt
set tgt.max_updatetimestamp = src.maxstamp
from (select id, max(updatetimestamp) as maxstamp from <tablename> group by 1) src
where tgt.id = src.id;
```